# how do you replace a value and restore its old value after 5 minutes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, settimeout

I have a value x = 5;

I need to replace x value to 10 for 5 minutes and restore it's old value (5) after 5 minutes. How do i achieve this using React-Redux.

My code:

on click of a button, i am triggering a function called sendValue

```
const x = 5;

onSubmit={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    timeInterval = setInterval(() => {
                        sendValue(x);

                    }, timeDelay);


                }}
```

act.sendValue.js is an action file which looks like below:

```
export const sendValue = (x) => async dispatch => {

  // other code

  dispatch({
    type: SEND_VALUE,
    payload: {
      initialValue: x
    }
  });

};
```

On click of another button, I am calling a function called updateValue

act.updateValue is the action which looks like below:

```
const x = 5;
export const updatePackagesLoad = (x) => async dispatch => {

let newValue;
  setTimeout(function () {
     newValue = x + 5; // updating x value to 10 for 5 minutes
    alert();
  }, 300000);


  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_VALUE,
    payload: {
      updatedValue: newValue
    }
  });

};
```

My reducer file, rdc.values.js looks like below:

```
const initialState = { countValue : 5 }

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case SEND_VALUE:
            return {
              ...state,
            countValue: payload.initialValue
            };
            case UPDATED_VALUE:
                return {
                  ...state,
                countValue: payload.updatedValue
                };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Is my setTimeout function correct ? will this achieve the desired outcome of changing the x value from 5 to 10 for 6 mins ? If not how do i achieve this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should read the documentation of Redux-Saga. You can start a saga that does that action every 5 minutes as you like. And also it's very easy to send any action to redux.

[Redux Saga Documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

Example:

```
export function* updateEvery5Minutes() {
    while (true) {
        yield delay(1000 * 300) // 5 minutes
        yield put({type:'ACTION_TYPE', payload: 5}) // any redux action
    }
}
```

And just run the saga as you can see in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This starts with 10 and then wait 5 min then change it to 5 and then it will stop

```
setval=true 
var interv=setInterval(function () {
 if(setval){
 console.log('10'),
 setval=false
 return x=10
 }

 if(!setval){
  console.log('5')
 return x=5,  clearInterval(interv)
 }

}, 300000);
```

Comment: I need to update the x value from 5 to 10 only once. This new value (10)  has to stay for 5 minutes and then replaced back to old value (5) after 5 minutes.

Comment: @aki I have updated the code you can have look at it,  try it, and let me know if anything has to be changed